# Use Node.js to parse file contained in JSON sent via POST using NGX-formly and Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, forms, angular-formly

I've used NGX-formly's tutorial on how to add files to my forms

Link to tutorial: [formly-js.github.io](https://formly-js.github.io/ngx-formly/examples/other/input-file)

The files are added as a part of the form's JSON. When using console.log() to print the object it in the backend it looks like this:

{"file":{"0":{}}}

And when console.log'ing in the frontend it gives me this:
[[image: 2]]
and

[[image: 3]]

How do I approach parsing the file in my Express/Node.js backend? I've tried using multer but as it only supports "multi-part/formdata" it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've tried parsing it using upload.single('file') as a middleware on the endpoint

Comment: you must add those efforts in the question as well

Answer (score 0):

Check out [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) package for nodejs

After you have installed it and you checked out the examples, use this on service:

```
    public upload(file: File){
        let body = new FormData();
        body.append('uploadfield',file); //uploadfield is the name of the item in formdata you picked at multer, I think its 'file' on defualt.
        return new Promise(resolve => {
              this.http.post("http://api-endpoit",body).subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data);
              }, err => {
                alert(err); //or whatever you want to handle error
              });
            });
    }
```

On component:
(I assume file is private field - like you did console.log(this.file))

```
upload() {
this.uploadService.upload(this.file).then(res => {
     if(res['success']) {
         ....
      }
  });
```